# StringExpression inconsistency using Alternative

Tags: regular-expressions

**Preface:** This will turn out to be a bad case of brain-malfunction. In any case, the precedence is surprising and I haven't checked the `FullForm`... the one thing we tell every new user. Oh my

---

This question is for reference. I believe this is a bug. Assume you want to match 3 cases: `123`, `.123`, and (`123.` or `123.123`). The documentation of `StringExpression` states:

> [image: img]

Let's try both versions we can use:

```
n1 = {DigitCharacter .., "." ~~ DigitCharacter .., 
      DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...};

n2 = DigitCharacter .. | "." ~~ DigitCharacter .. |
     DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...;
```

Now you will note that the created regular expressions look differently

```
First[StringPattern`PatternConvert[#]] & /@ {n1, n2}
```

> ```
> {
>  "(?ms)(?:\\d+|\\.\\d+|\\d+\\.\\d*)", 
>  "(?ms)(?:\\d+|\\.)(?:\\d+|\\d+)\\.\\d*"
> }
> ```

and in fact, they have different semantics

```
StringMatchQ[".1", #] & /@ {n1, n2}
(* {True, False} *)
```

Any suggestions, why this shouldn't be a bug?

Comment: How did you find `StringPattern\`PatternConvert`?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch A bad case of `Trace` that I used to solve a users problem some years ago. It is quite handy at times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) of `n2`:

```
n2 = DigitCharacter .. | "." ~~ DigitCharacter .. | DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...;
n2 //FullForm
```

> StringExpression[Alternatives[Repeated[DigitCharacter],"."],Alternatives[Repeated[DigitCharacter],Repeated[DigitCharacter]],".",RepeatedNull[DigitCharacter]]

Note that the head is not [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives). The issue is the precedence of `|` vs `~~`. The following version works:

```
n2 = Alternatives[
    DigitCharacter ..,
    "." ~~ DigitCharacter ..,
    DigitCharacter .. ~~ "." ~~ DigitCharacter ...
];
StringMatchQ[".1", n2]
```

> True

Comment: Nice! Indeed, I looked at the full-form but it's already 5:25 in the morning and I must have missed this obviously. I just assumed that `Alternatives` is `Flat`. Oh my.. Thanks.

Comment: In any case, this is a bad trap and makes the documentation that says **or** very questionable. Who uses an even mildly interesting regex without the `~~` operator?

Comment: Forget the `Flat` comment. It's far too late.